# Delete long text in TagInput

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have **`TagsInput`** where the user can enter any data (assumed to be links). Since links can be very long, I need a way to shorten their display so that the window does not stretch too much. I solved it with `white-space: nowrap`

Since I'm using **`TagsInput`**, the user should be able to delete the input. I have this functionality. And as you can see, it works on short links. But if the link is long, this cross is at the end and, accordingly, it is not visible. I would like everything to be displayed as follows (I marked the desired functionality in red):

Thus, I want the user to be able to delete a long link

```
.tag {
    display:flexbox;
    /* align-items: center; */
    margin: 5px 0;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: black;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: fit-content;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Just in case, the part of the code where I define the button to remove the tag

```
...
    const deleteTag = (index) => {
    setTags(prevState => prevState.filter((tag, i) => i !== index))
}

return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
        {tags.map((tag, index) => <div className={classes.tag}>
            {tag}
            <ClearIcon className={classes.del} fontSize="small" onClick={() => deleteTag(index)} />
        </div>
        )}
        <input
            className={classes.input}
            value={input}
            placeholder={props.inputPlaceholder}
            onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
            onKeyUp={onKeyUp}
            onChange={onChange}
        />
    </div>);
}
```

Comment: did you try to separate the input field/tag and the delete button? , so let's say your input gets max-width 200px and after that comes an inline button to delete this tag.

Comment: @MertHaddad Thanks for the advice. No, I have not tried this option. Could you help me with the code to implement this?

Comment: sure but if you can provide a demo that would be easier, you can use sandbox or fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to make it simple then you need to restructure your JSX:

```
<div className="tag">
  <div className="tag-name">www.google.com/dummytext/123</div>
  <ClearIcon className={classes.del} fontSize="small" onClick={() =>deleteTag(index)} />
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.tag {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  max-width: fit-content;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.tag-name {
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: -moz-fit-content;
  max-width: fit-content;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes it partially works. But the tag delete icon has moved down. Can it be returned to its original place somehow?

Comment: Try giving `flex-direction:row ` to tag class .

Comment: Unfortunately your version doesn't work.